# how to make loop like this in python?

Tags: python, php

I have php code like this

```
$array = array('1','2','3');
for ($i1=0; $i1<count($array);$i1++)
{
    for ($i2=$i1+1; $i2<count($array);$i2++)
    {
         echo $array[$i1].' '.$array[$i2];
    }
}
```

i want to write this code in python

Comment: So what did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: I want ro write it in Cobol;:-) i did not make an effort to do it. Please help (hoping you see the irony of my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
array = ['1', '2', '3']

for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(array)):
        print( f"{array[i]} {array[j]}" )
```

Output:

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

Comment: thanks sir this code word for me. but my result like this sir ```['1 2', '1 3', '2 1', '2 3', '3 1', '3 2']```